# Is there any resource on a environment setup for DJANGO and VueJS . I dont find much resources online can anyboody help me with that

Tags: django, vue.js

I got some articles related to django and vue environment setup. But it isn't Much clear about how to set up environment and how do they interact with each other.

An articles on medium which uses existing environment setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This https://www.fullstackpython.com/vuejs.html. One of the best resources for me in learning django.